# Azure DevOps Extract Files task doesn't preserve hierarchy

Tags: azure-devops

I am new to ADO, so am probably misunderstanding this, or just doing it wrong, so please be patient.

I want to deploy my web site to my server via FTP. As far as I can see, the build creates a zip file, which I need to extract, and then upload the extracted file. Please correct me if I got this wrong, because if I did, then what follows is probably irrelevant.

I have set up a release pipeline (started with an empty one) and added an Extract Files agent job...

[image]

I then added an FTP Upload task to upload the extracted files to my server...

[image]

The problem is that my server ends up with all of the files in the root folder. The hierarchy has been lost completely...

[image]

There should be a `wwwroot` folder there with the static content. The folder doesn't exist, and the static files (such as the `*.js` and `*.css` files you see in the screenshot) are all in the root folder.

The zip file did contain this folder...

[image]

Anyone able to explain what I did wrong?

Comment: Can you ensure the zip include the `wwwroot` folder? is the zip come from the build artifacts?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Sorry, forgot to mention that. I did download the zip, and saw that the wwwroot folder was there. Please see my updated question

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Can you confirm that I'm even doing this the right way? Might as well get the basic idea right first! Thanks

Comment: I just wanted to ask if you check the folder after you extract the zip before you uploaded with FTP, but @Leo post an answer that I think can helps you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Azure DevOps Extract Files task doesn't preserve hierarchy

When you want to keep folder structure with FTP Upload task, you can select the checkbox **preserve file paths** in the FTP Upload task settings.

If you didn't, please check it, then the files folder structure will be preserved:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent, that seems to have done it. Not sure why this isn't checked by default, seems highly illogical to want to flatten it all out. Any comments? Thanks

Comment: This is now default behavior; there's no longer the option to flatten paths.